# Lots of bouncing balls sink into each other

Tags: movement, physics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm trying to model a system that simulates an arbitrary number of bouncing balls with some gravity. So far I've come up with a solution that can be seen here: https://github.com/ahahalol/BouncingBalls

It works fine if the number of balls is small (a few dozens) or if I do not set any gravity. But once I turn gravity on and set the number of balls to a few hundreds, the balls "on the bottom" start sinking into each other over time as new balls fall on them "from the top".

Here's a picture that shows lots of sinking balls when I have gravity and hundreds of balls: 
[image]

I want a system that perfectly simulates rigid balls physics: no matter how many objects "on top" push the ones "on bottom", nothing should ever sink. How can I achieve this?

Comment: that's a pretty broad question.. i believe you need to be a bit more specific than "how can i achieve this" if you want an actual answer in your question.. i think that any good physics engine can do exactly what you described above

Comment: Yeah; this seems like it's just buggy behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say I have three circles. (I'm gonna say circles because if I called them balls, that sentence would sound weird.) 
What this example is doing is looking if two circles are overlapping. If they overlap, it'll calculate the distance between the two circles, and the required distance based on the radiusses (radii? whatever). It then moves the circles away from eachother.

As I mentioned, we have three circles. Circles A, B, and C are right next to eachother, lined up.  We move circle A to the right (to the other circles). First, it checks if circles A and B overlap. They do, so the function moves them away from eachother, and they don't overlap. Then it checks if circles A and C are overlapping. They don't. Circles B and C? They do, because circle B has been moved to the right. So the calculation runs again, pushing them away from eachother. All circles have now been checked for collision with all other circles, but because circle B has been pushed back to the left by the last collision check, it's overlapping with circle A!

A way to resolve this would be to check, when two circles overlap, if moving both of them will cause one of them to overlap with another circle. You could then check if you can move that other circle away to make room, but this would take an absurd amount of resources to pull off. It's unusable for a game. What to do: get more room or less circles.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, looks like my position correction algorithm is indeed rather naïve. But theoretically I do have enough room since there's no upper boundary set in code. How do physics engines handle there situations, are there any special strategies I can apply?

Comment: You could of course sort your array, list or whatever collection you're using, by the y position of your circles. This way, you could check the bottom circle first, and make everything expand upwards. This would by no means be a perfect solution, but it would give better results. However, since I have never handled large collections before, I don't know how sorting them manually by y value would impact performance, and what kind of collection would be best.

Comment: Just tried that. Circles behave differently but still bad. I guess I'll have to proceed using some existing physics library.